# Copy files from share Windows network folders?

Tags: remote

CentOS, Emacs 27.2

In local network have Windows machine with name **someWindowsHost**. This machine share folder **\shared\some_windows_folder**.
And if I want to copy some files from this share folder I start my Windows Virtual machine(on VirtualBox).  On my Windows open **File explorer** and in address input smt like this:

```
\\someWindowsHost\shared\some_windows_folder
```

As result open content of this network shared folder. And now I can copy files that I need.

Nice... but it's to many steps.

The question is:
Is it possible from Linux (CentOS) machine by Emacs copy files from this share Windows folder?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you want to do this from Emacs, read the Tramp documentation, with special attention to the section on SMB. Dired works over Tramp, so you can copy files that way. Alternatively, if you are using Gnome or KDE, your file manager should be able to open SMB URL paths like smb://someWindowsHost/someShare/someWindowsFolder/.